# Issue with ArrayList from JSON using Retrofit and populating RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I’ve been trying to get recycler view working with retrofit. I seem to be pulling in the JSON fine from within getRecipes() method, and my logs are showing me that the some data is there.

However, when I call my getRecipes() method from onCreate(), something seems to be going wrong. When I check to see if my recipeList array contains my JSON results within onCreate, it is telling me it is empty. Why is it doing this if my logs within my getRecipes() method are showing me that data is there...?

Not sure if it is an issue with my recycler view or what I am doing with retrofit, or something else. Been trying for days to figure out, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

JSON 
https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json

```
public class ItemListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean mTwoPane;
public static final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
public static List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getRecipes();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    getRecipes();

    //Logging to check that recipeList contains data

    if(recipeList.isEmpty()){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Is empty");
    }else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Is not empty");
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.item_list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter simpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter = new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(recipeList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {

        mTwoPane = true;
    }

}


public void getRecipes(){

    String ROOT_URL = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/";

    Retrofit RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RecipeService service = RETROFIT.create(RecipeService.class);

    Call<List<Recipe>> call = service.getMyJson();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Recipe>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Response<List<Recipe>> response) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got here");
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No Success");
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got here");

            recipeList = response.body();

            //Logging to check data is there
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "LOGS" + recipeList.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < recipeList.size(); i++) {
                String newString = recipeList.get(i).getName();

                Ingredients[] ingredients = recipeList.get(i).getIngredients();
                for(int j = 0; j < ingredients.length; j++){
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, ingredients[j].getIngredient());
                }

                Steps[] steps = recipeList.get(i).getSteps();
                for(int k = 0; k < steps.length; k++){
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, steps[k].getDescription());
                }

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, newString);


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("getRecipes throwable: ", t.getMessage());
            t.printStackTrace();

        }
    });


}



public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Recipe> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Recipe> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getName());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.getId());
                    ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.getId());

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public  View mView;
        public  TextView mContentView;
        public Recipe mItem;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

RecipeService

```
public interface RecipeService {
@GET("baking.json")
Call<List<Recipe>> getMyJson();}
```

Models

Recipe

```
public class Recipe{

private Ingredients[] ingredients;

private String id;

private String servings;

private String name;

private String image;

private Steps[] steps;

public Ingredients[] getIngredients ()
{
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients (Ingredients[] ingredients)
{
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getServings ()
{
    return servings;
}

public void setServings (String servings)
{
    this.servings = servings;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage ()
{
    return image;
}

public void setImage (String image)
{
    this.image = image;
}

public Steps[] getSteps ()
{
    return steps;
}

public void setSteps (Steps[] steps)
{
    this.steps = steps;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "[ingredients = "+ingredients+", id = "+id+", servings = "+servings+", name = "+name+", image = "+image+", steps = "+steps+"]";
}}
```

Ingredients

```
public class Ingredients{
private String measure;

private String ingredient;

private String quantity;

public String getMeasure ()
{
    return measure;
}

public void setMeasure (String measure)
{
    this.measure = measure;
}

public String getIngredient ()
{
    return ingredient;
}

public void setIngredient (String ingredient)
{
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}

public String getQuantity ()
{
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity (String quantity)
{
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "[measure = "+measure+", ingredient = "+ingredient+", quantity = "+quantity+"]";
}}
```

Steps

```
public class Steps{

private String id;
     private String shortDescription;

    private String description;

    private String videoURL;

    private String thumbnailURL;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getShortDescription ()
    {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription (String shortDescription)
    {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getVideoURL ()
    {
        return videoURL;
    }

    public void setVideoURL (String videoURL)
    {
        this.videoURL = videoURL;
    }

    public String getThumbnailURL ()
    {
        return thumbnailURL;
    }

    public void setThumbnailURL (String thumbnailURL)
    {
        this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[id = "+id+", shortDescription = "+shortDescription+", description = "+description+", videoURL = "+videoURL+", thumbnailURL = "+thumbnailURL+"]";
    }}
```

Logs

https://gist.github.com/2triggers/12b6eeb32ed8909ab50bbadd4742d7f7

Comment: try debug and check  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "LOGS" + recipeList.size()); what is the size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you are sending the recipelist into the adapter before even it is populated , after you are sending the recipelist into the adapter which is empty you are populating your recipelist from getRecipes method, you might be wondering you have declared the getRecipes method before even you are assigning the recipelist to adapter so how come it is empty, yea but the fact is your getRecipes work on background thread so even before your recipelist gets populated your adapter assignment takes place on the main thread so you are basically assigning the empty list, one thing you can do is notify when the adapter when the data changes or when the the recipelist is filled with data that is from within the getRecipe method.

when you assign the recipelist = response.body right after this you can notify the adapter

or move this two lines

```
SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter simpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter = new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(recipeList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

right after the

```
 recipelist = response.body;
```

in getRecipes method

Comment: YEEEESSSSSSSSS! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

this will be empty always because this line will execute before getting the response from a server.

```
if(recipeList.isEmpty()){
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Is empty");
    }else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Is not empty");
    }
```

Better call this after this line recipeList = response.body();

```
SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter simpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter = new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(recipeList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {

            mTwoPane = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try create the Constructor with all atributes from your Recipe.class

Like: 
    public Ingredients(String measure, String      ingredients, String quantity ){
    this.measure = measure;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.quantity = quantity
    }

Do same in all class where make up your object of list.